# SQL : Adding lines in a query result depending on returned data

Tags: sql

Sorry for the title, not easy to phrase it correctly.

I have a table A which has a business key (Akey) with possible value range : k1, k2 and k3

```
AKey ACol2  ACol3
k1   val12  val13
k2   val22  val23
k3   val32  val33
```

I have a table B which has entries like

```
BKey1 BKey2 BKey3  AKey Col5  Col6
kk11  kk12  kk13   k1   val15 val16
kk21  kk22  kk23   k3   val25 val26
```

BKey1, BKey2 and Bkey3 is the business key of table B
Akey is a foreign key to table A

I would like to generate a result set with table B joined with table A (on AKey) but include "empty" lines for non referenced key from table A (and this for each key of table B). In the example I would like to have :

```
BKey1 BKey2 BKey3  AKey Col5  Col6   ACol2 ACol3
kk11  kk12  kk13   k1   val15 val16  val12 val13
kk21  kk22  kk23   k3   val25 val26  val32 val33
kk11  kk12  kk13   k2   def   def    val22 val23
kk11  kk12  kk13   k3   def   def    val32 val33
kk21  kk22  kk23   k1   def   def    val12 val13
kk21  kk22  kk23   k2   def   def    val22 val23
```

I have two entries just like for the inner join + entries for all other key range values of A (k1, k2 and k3) with default values (that I need to set) for columns of B. I tried a right join but then I only have default entries once in the result and not for each key of B. Can you help me in the right direction to achieve this ?

Christian

Comment: you mean you need a left join instead of the inner join?

Comment: The output results make sense, but they're not the product of a trivial join. The number of result rows is the product of rows in A and B, as there is no limitation (no `WHERE A.x = B.y` clause). The first three columns of the output come from B, the fourth and last two from A (as the preix indicates). `Col5` and `Col6` come from a subquery, which _does_ have a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select D.BKey1,
       D.BKey2,
       D.BKey3,
       D.AKey,
       coalesce(B.Col5, 'def') as Col5,
       coalesce(B.Col6, 'def') as Col6,
       A.ACol2,
       A.ACol3
from (select B.BKey1, B.BKey2, B.BKey3, A.AKey
      from TableA as A
        cross join (select distinct BKey1, BKey2, BKey3
                    from TableB
                   ) as B
     ) as D
  inner join TableA as A
    on A.AKey = D.AKey
  left outer join TableB as B
    on B.BKey1 = D.BKey1 and 
       B.BKey2 = D.BKey2 and 
       B.BKey3 = D.BKey3 and 
       B.AKey = D.AKey
```

For test:

```
with TableA(AKey, ACol2,  ACol3) as
(
select 'k1',   'val12',  'val13' union all
select 'k2',   'val22',  'val23' union all
select 'k3',   'val32',  'val33'
),
TableB(BKey1, BKey2, BKey3,  AKey, Col5,  Col6) as
(
select 'kk11',  'kk12',  'kk13',   'k1',   'val15', 'val16' union all
select 'kk11',  'kk12',  'kk13',   'k2',   'valx',  'valy'  union all
select 'kk21',  'kk22',  'kk23',   'k3',   'val25', 'val26'
)

select D.BKey1,
       D.BKey2,
       D.BKey3,
       D.AKey,
       coalesce(B.Col5, 'def') as Col5,
       coalesce(B.Col6, 'def') as Col6,
       A.ACol2,
       A.ACol3
from (select B.BKey1, B.BKey2, B.BKey3, A.AKey
      from TableA as A
        cross join (select distinct BKey1, BKey2, BKey3
                    from TableB
                   ) as B
     ) as D
  inner join TableA as A
    on A.AKey = D.AKey
  left outer join TableB as B
    on B.BKey1 = D.BKey1 and 
       B.BKey2 = D.BKey2 and 
       B.BKey3 = D.BKey3 and 
       B.AKey = D.AKey
```

Result:

```
BKey1 BKey2 BKey3 AKey Col5  Col6  ACol2 ACol3
----- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----- -----
kk11  kk12  kk13  k1   val15 val16 val12 val13
kk11  kk12  kk13  k2   valx  valy  val22 val23
kk11  kk12  kk13  k3   def   def   val32 val33
kk21  kk22  kk23  k1   def   def   val12 val13
kk21  kk22  kk23  k2   def   def   val22 val23
kk21  kk22  kk23  k3   val25 val26 val32 val33
```

Test it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/103394/sql-adding-lines-in-a-query-result-depending-on-returned-data).

Comment: Just about to post similar. Still doesn't make a while heap of sense to my mind.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. That's clearly the right direction but I did a mistake in my problem description -> AKey in table B is also part of the business key of table B and the select with cross join gives me too many results in this case

Comment: @Christian – You should add some more sample data that will show that behavior. With the data provided here you get what you want.

Comment: You're right, just add in table B a line like kk11 kk12 kk13 k2 valx valy. I found something complex by adding a group by but there might be a better solution for sure

Comment: @Christian – Then you would have 9 rows in the output. What rows don't you want?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not always clear ;-) I need 6 lines in fact. For each key of B (BKey1, BKey2, BKey3), I want to have as many entries as there are different values in A (k1, k2, k3). In my example, for key (kk11, kk12, kk13) in B, I already have an entry for k1 and k2 and I need an additional entry for k3. For key (kk21,kk22,kk23) I have already entry for k3 and I need additional entries for k1 and k2. I hope it's clearer !

Comment: @Christian – Ok. But what values do you need in column `Col5` and `Col6` for `kk11, kk12, kk13`? `val15, val16` or `valx, valy`? And what is the criteria to choose one before the other?

Comment: My expected result is as described in the initial question.Since we added an entry to B (kk11,kk12,kk13,k2,valx,valy) in the example, it's just that the third line in the expected result would become (kk11,kk12,kk13,k2,valx,valy,val22,val23) instead of having "def" (default) in them. Said otherwise, table A contains a discrete set of values. Table B contains entries with foreign key to A.My problem is that for a given key in B, not all values from the discrete set of A are present. When a value of A is not present I just need to add the lines with some default value for the other columns of B.

Comment: @Christian – It got a bit messy there for a while but I think I got it now.

Comment: Thanks again Mikael, that's perfect !